# mysql: one to many to itself and join

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
id   name     parent_id
0    fruit    NULL
1    place    NULL
2    apple    0
3    orange   0
4    beach    1
5    forest   1
```

and I want to get a result like this:

```
id   name    name
0    fruit   NULL
1    place   NULL
2    apple   fruit
3    orange  fruit
4    beach   place
5    forest  place
```

I have tried with this:

```
SELECT * FROM foobar LEFT OUTER JOIN foobar c ON c.parent_id = c.id
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: this could have been googled.

Answer (score 2):

In your `JOIN` you are joing `c` to **itself**. You have to join `c` to `foobar`. Try this:

```
SELECT foobar.id, foobar.name, c.name FROM foobar LEFT OUTER JOIN foobar c ON foobar.parent_id = c.id
```

Comment: `select *` and `join` together?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, a.name as [parent] FROM foobar a LEFT OUTER JOIN foobar c ON c.parent_id = a.id
```